use a dynamic value for timestamp with time zone in postgres
I want to replace static (hard-coded) with dynamic timestamp with time zone value. For instance replacing '2024-06-03 00:00:00+00' with date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 month').
That is, replacing
select * from my_table where timestamp >= '2024-06-02 00:00:00+00';

With
select * from my_table where timestamp >= date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 month');

When the dynamic value is used, the query's result is different than when the static value is used where both (dynamic or static) values are the same.
The datatype of the timestamp column in my_table is timestamp with time zone, which is the same datatype returned by date_trunc().
psql=> \d my_table;
  Column  |           Type
----------+-------------------------
title     | text
timestamp | timestamp with time zone


psql=> select pg_typeof(date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 month'));
        pg_typeof
--------------------------
 timestamp with time zone

psql=> select date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 month');
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2024-06-03 00:00:00+00
(1 row)

psql=> select date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 month') = '2024-06-03 00:00:00+00' as equal;
 equal
-------
 t
(1 row)

The query returns a good result when manually copying the result of date_trunc() as a static value for the timestamp column.
Any idea what is wrong when using a dynamic value for the timestamp column?
Update:
I am running the following psql and Postgres versions
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

psql=> SELECT version();
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| version                                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PostgreSQL 14.2 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

with UTC timezone
psql=> show timezone;
+----------+
| TimeZone |
+----------+
| UTC      |
+----------+


This doesn't seem likely. I don't suppose you can come up with a reproducible example of some data + query that behaves differently with a calculated vs literal timestamptz comparison?

@RichardHuxton If I had an reproducible example to share, believe me that I would. The table itself is a Foreign data wrappers on external provider that I am integrating with. Anyhow, I've updated my post with query example. Although there is no reproducible example, do you have any lead?

@Zegarek I want to replace static (hard-coded) with dynamic timestamp with time zone value

@Zegarek In the value for the column in the query. Refer to the query example.

Sorry, I guess I'm overthinking this a bit. Have you checked whether the TimeZone and DateStyle setting are the same everywhere you test this? The latter may swap month and day fields, the former shifts the value. Also, there are different meanings of different formats of the offset you see in the value. I would bet one of these three things, if nothing else.

@Zegarek Maybe you say wise things. Too wise for me to understand. Could you share a snippet for clarity?

To your question text add 1) Postgres version. 2) Where you got or are running the Postgres instance. 3) The client you are running the queries in. 4) The output from show timezone; 5) What exactly the difference is between the queries.

@AdrianKlaver I've updated the details

From here date_trunc: When the input value is of type timestamp with time zone, the truncation is performed with respect to a particular time zone; for example, truncation to day produces a value that is midnight in that zone. . If you want it to be equivalent to the hard coded value you need to do: select date_trunc('day', (now() - interval '1 day') - interval '1 month');. That is assuming this: timestamp >= '2024-06-02 00:00:00+00' is really what you want.

@AdrianKlaver It did not work. Meaning, when using your date_trunc() in the query, the result is not the same as taking the output of your select date_trunc() and replacing it in the query.

You need to add the exact query you used and the output as update to question text.

@AdrianKlaver It is already in the question. What am I missing?

Not the revised query using my suggestion. Show it and it's output as update to question.
